# Estou com duvida nesse enigma, não consigo achar o erro no programa

Tags: c

ola eu estou com duvida nesse codigo não consigo achar o erro, alguem poderia mediser onde eu estou errando?

```
int main(){

char n_a[500]
char cit[500];
float codigo,n1,n2,n_l;
printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("Nome do aluno: ");
scanf("%[^\n]s",&n_a);
printf("\nNome da cidade onde o  aluno mora: ");
scanf("%[^\n]s",&cit);
setbuf(stdin,NULL);
printf("\nEscreva o codigo do aluno: ");
scanf("%f",&codigo);
printf("\nNota da 1º prova: ");
scanf("%f",&n1);
printf("\nNota da 2º prova: ");
scanf("%f",&n2);
printf("\nNota do laboratorio: ");
scanf("%f",&n_l);
//gatchar();
printf("\n------------------------------------------------\n");
//printf("\e[H\e[2J");
//system("cls");
printf("O aluno%s", n_a ,"nascido na cidade de%s", cit ,"está cursando a disciplina “Lógica de");
printf("\nProgramação” com código%d" , codigo ,"e sua notas do curso são:");
printf("\nNota da prova 1:%f",n1,"\nNota da prova 2%f",n2,"\nNota do laboratorio\n%f",n_l);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cara, seus `printf` estão errados, não é assim que usa

Comment: Onde está o enigma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando a função printf errada, quando coloca o % e segue com o a indicação do tipo depois já esta "reservando" o local da variavel.

Ex.:

```
.
.
.
char Nome[20] = "Niguém";
int idade = 20;
printf("Nome: %s\nIdade: %i", Nome, idade)
.
.
.
Saída : Nome: Niguém
        Idade: 20</pre>
```